# MapReduce in python: os.environ ["map_input_file"] dosen't work in map.py

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

This is my first time to study Hadoop MapReduce with python.

I wrote a map.py to get filenames of two files in order to learn how to join two files.
Here are two CSV files:

*worksheet1.csv*

```
sno,name
1,name1
2,name2
3,name3
4,name4
```

*worksheet2.csv*

```
sno,courseno,grade
1,1,80
1,2,90
2,1,82
2,2,95
```

map.py:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

def mapper():

    filepath = os.environ["map_input_file"] 
    filename = os.path.split(filepath)[-1]  #get the names
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if line.strip()=="":
            continue
        fields = line[:-1].split("\t") 
        sno = fields[0]   #get student ID

        if filename == 'worksheet1':
            #get student ID and name, mark 0
            name = fields[1] 
            print '\t'.join((sno,'0',name)) 
        elif filename == 'worksheet2':
            #get student ID, course number, grade, mark 1
            courseno = fields[1]
            grade = fields[2]
            print '\t'.join((sno,'1',courseno,grade)) 


if __name__=='__main__':
    mapper()
```

Then I use

```
    $cat worksheet1 worksheet2 |python map.py
```

to test the program.

The error shows below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map.py", line 30, in <module>
    mapper()
  File "map.py", line 11, in mapper
    filepath = os.environ['map_input_file']
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'map_input_file'
```

Please tell me why and how to modify the code.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Just because your environnement variable `map_input_file` doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set up `map_input_file` environment variable. Also, you're piping your data files to your script so that they will be available as `sys.stdin` in the script, but your code to discover which of them is currently being read is completely wrong. I suggest just using `fileinput` module.

Comment: Maybe I can use `len()` to distinguish two files rather than use its filenames.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test your program locally in this case.

When you run Hadoop Streaming, `os.environ['map_input_file']` will be set by Hadoop framework so that you can get the filename. However, when you run locally, nobody set that for you.

So don't test it on your local machine, simply run it on Hadoop.

By the way, it'a bad practice to distinguish different files by checking number of fields, e.g, `len(line.split(","))`. For you won't be so lucky that different files always have different `len()`  . And if you are dealing with files produced by others, you will be mad if they change the format of the files in the future(e.g, add more fields).